# Whats the alternative tag for height in slds

Tags: slds

I Placed Lightning Componet in community.But this is small component,because of that reason  footer is appeaing near to that component.

Logically footer needs to appear in bottom so What I did,

I used

```
      <div style="height:290px;">
```

**it works specially for device**.Instead of Height which tag I need to make it work for all devicess

```
 <div style="height:290px;">
    <lightning:button label="Claim Now" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
    <div  class="slds-m-top_large">
        <a onclick="{!c.homedetails}" style="width:100%;" data-index="{!index}">Return To Home</a> |
        <a onclick="{!c.incentivesdetails}" style="width:100%;" data-index="{!index}">Return To Incentives</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Docked Footer from SLDS

```
<div style="height: 180px;">
  <div class="slds-docked-form-footer">
    <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/docked-form-footer/#site-main-content)